# MemberPress current user subscription id

Tags: wordpress, memberpress

I'm trying to get the subscription ID(s) for the current user in MemberPress.  Can't find any examples of this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$user = new MeprUser( get_current_user_id());

$subscriptions = $user->active_product_subscriptions('ids');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$active_subscription_ids = MeprUtils::get_currentuserinfo()->active_product_subscriptions('ids');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = get_current_user_id();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.